# Prediction depends on batch size

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, semantic-segmentation

I have trained a model for semantic segmentation in Tensorflow. I want to run the predictions of a set of 64 new images (they are greyscale images, therefore the number of channels is 1). For this, I wrote two methods and compare the results (I initially expected that they would provide the same value):

1. Method A: Load all the images into a 4D array (NB_IMAGES, ROWS, COLS, 1). I run the prediction in the entire 4D array, i.e., all images at the same time (Batch size=64).
2. Method B: I run the predictions in each image separately. Each image is loaded as a 4D array of the shape (1, ROWS, COLS, 1). Batch size=1.

Method A provided this result for one of the classes: [image: Batch_size = 64], and method B provided this: [image: batch_size=1]

Method B provides more information than method B. In addtion, Method B provides the predictions in float64, whereas method A generates a float32 array.

Here is the code:

```
for i, x in enumerate(img_list):
        
  
        with Image.open(os.path.join(imgset_path, x)) as img_i:
            img_i = np.array(img_i.convert('L'))
        
        img_i_np = np.copy(img_i)
        img_i_np = np.expand_dims(img_i_np, -1) # Expand dims and normalize
        img_i_np = np.expand_dims(img_i_np, 0)
        img_i_np - img_i_np.astype('float64')/255.
        original[i,:,:,:] = np.copy(img_i_np[0,:,:,:])
        
        img_i_np_check = np.copy(img_i)
        img_i_np_check = np.expand_dims(img_i_np_check, -1)
        img_i_np_check = np.expand_dims(img_i_np_check, 0)
        img_i_np_check = img_i_np_check.astype('float64')/255.
                
        
        pred_i = model.predict(img_i_np_check)  # Method B
        preds_check[i,:,:,:] = pred_i[0,:,:,:]
        
        list_originals += [(x, i)]
     
        
    # Run predictions
    preds = model.predict(original) # Method A
```

I'm really lost about these differences in the predictions, considering that the model is the same, no batch_normalization was used and the data set is also the same. Does anybody know or have any experience regarding the effect of batch size and prediction?

Comment: It's a bug somewhere, batch size does not affect prediction. Could you make a reproducible code or colab or something?

Comment: Hi,I have just created a colab (I included the model and the parameters used for training): https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1moHCzJlvoc4KXdOFpwQTqBaQLJ9paeHi?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi, I opened this new question as I discovered new things along the way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68471788/segmentation-probablity-maps-depend-on-cpu-or-gpu-prediction

Comment: Does this help https://medium.com/mini-distill/effect-of-batch-size-on-training-dynamics-21c14f7a716e

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I am having similar issue in my model

Comment: @TarunMishra I managed to understand why this is happening:  You can find more in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68471788/segmentation-probablity-maps-depend-on-cpu-or-gpu

Comment: @TarunMishra Long Story short: Difference in predictions do not depend on the batch size, but in the hardware. Results provided  by CPU and GPU are different by a very very small amount as the computation mechanisms are different. This is acknowledged here: https://keras.io/getting_started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-results-using-keras-during-development