# Segmentation probablity maps depend on CPU or GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, semantic-segmentation

I wrote a model for semantic segmentation in tensorflow. The model were trained in a CPU and the predictions were also done in a CPU.
After some time I run the predictions again in a GPU machine and I noticed that there were some very small differences in the probability maps (Figure attached).
In addition, I wanted to check if the batch size affected the prediction distribution (I initially thought that there were no influence).

I ran a small experiment describing these four situations:

A1) Model Trained in CPU and Predictions run in CPU --> Batch Size = 1

A2) Model Trained in CPU and Prediction run in CPU  --> Batch Size = 64

B1) Model Trained in CPU and Predictions run in GPU --> Batch Size = 1

B2) Model Trained in CPU and Prediction run in GPU  --> Batch Size = 64

I have summarized the results for a portion of one of the images in the test set in the Figure attached.

We can observe that:

1. Training the model and running the predictions in a CPU provides the same results regardless the batch size.
2. Batch size has an effect (although small) when training the model in a CPU and running the predictions in a GPU
3. Predictions provided by a CPU and a GPU don't match (very small differences). This can be relevant if the cutoff threshold is placed at 0.55, then according to the Figure attached, the CPU will classify it as a background pixel (0.549857<0.55) , whereas the GPU will classify it as a foreground pixel (0.550076>0.55) if the image was part of a larger batch.
4. Running the GPU predictions again, provide different probabilities (very small differences again), whereas CPU provides always the same probabilities.

Here is the link to the [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1moHCzJlvoc4KXdOFpwQTqBaQLJ9paeHi?usp=sharing) to reproduce the feature.

So my main question is:

- Is this behaviour something normal that is expected to happen?
- Why this behavior happens (documentation)?
- How can I avoid this to happen? So that the Predictions run in a GPU always provide the same probabilities as the CPU) and regardless of the batch size?

[image]

Comment: Could you make everything float32 to make it a bit more apples to apples? I can't run your model because I don't have the weights. Just the random weights from whatever model you have should be fine (don't need to load weights), though you should set a seed, if you want to just put in the code for building/compiling the model.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Could you provide me an email address do that I could send you the weights file and a small data set so that you can try it out? if you wish, of course. Besides, do you know if i can choose the predictions to be given directly as float32? For method A i got them as float32, but for method B they are float64 and I dont know why...I'll apply your suggestions asap. Thanks again!

Comment: I have just added your suggestions (seed and convert the probability maps to float32). The differences I mentioned in the original post persist. Any idea?

Comment: Hmm, not sure. The percent difference is tiny, but that being said it shouldn't be there. If I get some time I'll see if I can replicate with other cases. You could submit a bug report to tensorflow as well (you'll have to make your sample run on it's own and be even more self-contained), which is one last step worth doing (just build your model with random initialization).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I have added the code for the model I used (very straight forward implementation of Unet). Also, here is the folder containing the model and some images Hi, thanks for your help. I have added the code for the model I used (very straight forward implementation of Unet). Also, here is the folder containing the model and some images *https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1YWXvM9h21DMu91trfyywoa--SGfqOneh?usp=sharing      How can I build the model with random initilalization? Thanks for your help again.

Comment: Hi again, just found this ressource in Keras documentation: https://keras.io/getting_started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-reproducible-results-using-keras-during-development   It is worth reading it as it actually says that GPUs produce non-deterministic outputs so it is recommended to run code in CPUs to obtain always the same result. I think this information is crucial for this problem. I have reported the bug to Keras anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Segmentation depends up on RAM. When processes are swap in and swap out in RAM then different kinds of algorithms are used. Segmentation depends up on Memory so, GPU is directly segmented on different chunks of the page frame.

Comment: So you mean, that the differences I got are something to expect when doing image segmentation with a GPU?

Comment: Do you have any kind of code or some other source to back up this assertion?

Answer (score 0):

This question was posted in [Keras' github](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/14986) and was answered accordingly by Keras' team.

The following keypoints could be made:

1. Running a model in GPU produces non-deterministic results (it provides a different output, even with really small differences, every time the model is run
2. CPU produces deterministic results (always the same results)
3. There are plans to make GPU predictions deterministic, but they still be slightly different to the CPU results.
4. Using the environmental variable `TF_DETERMINISTIC_OPS=1` in TF>2.5 helps with the non-deterministic behavior.